# How to disable cache in django view?

Tags: python, django, caching

Whenever I modify the django view or static files, it may still not update when I reload the page.

For example,

```
def index(request):
    print 'first'
    return httpResponse('ok')
```

The django server log returns 'first'

But After modification

```
def index(request):
    print 'second'
    return httpResponse('ok')
```

The django may still returns 'first', not 'second'.

I have found some way to disable cache

for example,

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def index(request):
    print 'second'
    return httpResponse('ok')
```

But it will not work.

How can I avoid this problem when in development mode?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you run your site in development mode? You might just need to restart the server for the changes to take effect. Django won't cache anything unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: by development mode, do you mean you use : python manage.py runserver ? if yes, nothing should be cached. Stupid question : do you save your modifications ? (dev server must restart automatically after each modifications)

Comment: @knbk, I run my development server by python manage.py runserver and set the DEBUG=true. Do I need to use such command to restart the dev server whenever I made change? This is terrible!

Comment: @RaphaëlBraud, yes! I use python manage.py runserver to start the dev server. And I am very sure that I already save the modifications. However, it seems the dev server not automatically restart to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with caching. Your devserver has not detected the change for some reason, so has not restarted; just do ctrl-c and re-run it manually.

Comment: But it always return 304 with page,  not 200.

Answer (score 0):

In **Chrome**, go to your browser settings, and you can `Disable cache`.  It is the first options under *settings > general*

Comment: it's not a matter of browser cache, as far as devserver doesn't restart, modifications won't be taken into account :)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, Django dev server detects changes in .py files that it loads when starting. Could you try to add

```
from your_app import index
```

for instance in your urls.py, just to be sure module is loaded.

Then modify index code.

Your devserver should restart.

If it restarts, your modifications will be taken into account and your print should be ok

Comment: Is there any way to know that the dev server has detected the change?

Comment: I have added ```from app_name import views``` in urls.py. But it still did not work.